My if statement isn't getting ignored after the == isn't the input it is required
after I run the code it still will be 15 even if the input isn't yes or Yes. I'm new to Python - can anyone please help me?
The statement:
if stuffed == "yes' or "Yes" :
    price = 15
else :
    price = 10

Even if the input isn't "yes" or "Yes", it will still say 15

This question is similar to: Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should use like below code:
if stuffed == "yes" or stuffed  == "Yes":
    price = 15
else:
    price = 10

